# iOS Customize Touch ID Failure?

Tags: ios, biometrics, touch-id

So I'm attempting to implement touchID in my app, but when I get a mismatch the standard alert for retry pops up. Clicking "Enter Password" does nothing (maybe because I'm on the simulator).

I'm wondering if it's possible to customize the options on that alert, maybe hide "Enter Password" so we can just leave cancel or retry as the only options for this scenario.

Currently I'm only handling success, and am unsure yet how to handle the failure case (i.e. what I can do in the else statement that goes with `if success`

Documentation seems to be purposely vague on the issue of how to actually handle failures.

Comment: I find the comments in the `LAError.h` header file more helpful than the official documentation. I think you can open it with the “Open Quickly” option in the File-menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it through experimentation. LAContext's `localizedFallbackTitle` holds the answer. It may default to "Enter Password" but setting it to an Empty String hides the button. Wish the documentation would have been more clear on that.